# Open Link from Bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, user-interface, primefaces

How can I open a link from bean?I will open something like www.google.de.It should open the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't open a link from a bean. A link requires enduser interaction.

Rather tell the browser directly to send a new GET request on the given URL. You can use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) for this.

```
public void action() throws IOException {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("http://www.google.de");
}
```

---

This makes however no sense if that's the sole action of the bean. Rather use `<h:outputLink>` or just `<a>` instead of `<h:commandLink action="#{bean.action}">` or something.

```
<h:outputLink value="http://www.google.de">link</h:outputLink>
<a href="http://www.google.de">link</a>
```